# How to define an object whose address is null?

Tags: c++, c, linker, weak-references

I am wondering how I can define an object in C whose reference will be null?

```
// definition of foo 
...
void * bar = &foo; // bar must be null
```

There is some ways I could find to do it, but none fit my needs.

```
__attribute__((weak)) extern int foo; //not working with cygwin/gcc 3.4
__attribute__((at(0))) int foo;       //only with rvds
#define foo (*(int*) 0)               //cannot be embedded in a macro
```

Actually, I would prefer a standard compliant solution (c99), but anything working
will be ok.

---

Edited: The reason to do this is that bar will not always be null. Here is a more relevant example:

```
// macro that will define foo to a real object or to *null
DECL(foo);

int * bar = &foo;

if(bar) {
  // we can call func
  func(bar);
} else {
  // bar undefined
  exit(-1);
}
```

Of course this is still not very relevant, because I can use #if in my condition. The project involves in fact big structures, a lot of files, a few compilers, some cpu targets, and many programmers who generate bugs with a probability exponential to the complexity of the syntax they use. It is why I would like a simple macro to declare my foo object.

Comment: struct oops { struct omg { template<typename T> operator T*() { return 0; } }; omg operator&() { return omg(); } } woops; int *p = &woops; assert(p == NULL) nastiness warning !! hehe

Comment: why isn't the above an answer? :) I'd vote it.

Comment: not sure which direction though.

Comment: I have to ask... why do you need to do this in the first place??

Comment: The reason it's not an answer is that the original poster wants a C99 solution, not a C++ solution.

Comment: @Thornley, The question states "anything working will be ok."  Also, the question has been tagged with "c++."

Comment: @calandoa, With your example, why not have DECL set a flag?  Or, why not DECL return a pointer (e.g. bar) itself?

Comment: @strager, There is actually several kind of DECLs, in different files and the equivalent of the int * bar = &foo; is in only one file, so the static condition would not work.

Comment: and how about this: void *null[] = {0}; #define foo null)[0][0]+(0
 .... char *c = (&foo); assert(c == NULL); nasty too though and parens needed

Comment: I think that you might want to reconsider how your DECL works, and instead have it make foo always be a pointer (of course that'll add to your complexity). As it stands, it's not clear what type foo has. Is it an object? Is it a pointer to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a symbol with an address of zero. Your last example is probably the only way of doing this within the C compiler / language.

The approach that is most likely to solve your problem is to look at the input file to the linker program. Most linkers allow you to define the label foo as zero.

In a unix ld script this is just:
foo = 0 ;

Answer (score 16):

I've got to be missing something, but what doesn't work about `void * bar = NULL`?

Comment: What we're missing is a clue of what the OP really wants to accomplish, actually.

Answer (score 2):

In your class, you can override the `&` operator:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass() :
            m_isNull(true)
        {
        }

        MyClass(int value) :
            m_isNull(),
            m_value(value)
        {
        }

        int value() const
        {
            /* If null, throw exception, maybe? */

            return m_value;
        }

        bool isNull() const
        {
            return m_isNull;
        }

        /////////////////////////
        // Here's the "magic". //
        /////////////////////////
        MyClass *operator&()
        {
            if(m_isNull)
                return 0;
            return this;
        }

    private:
        bool m_isNull;
        int m_value;
};
```

This produces behavior a user of `MyClass` would probably not expect.  I'm not sure where this "feature" would be required or even wanted.

If you want to take the real address of a `MyClass` instance, you can use `boost` (as suggested in the comments to this answer):

```
MyClass foo;

MyClass *fooptr = &foo; // fooptr == NULL
fooptr = boost::addressof(foo); // fooptr = &foo (the real address)
```

Or you can use casting, so `MyClass::operator&()` isn't called:

```
struct DummyStruct {};

MyClass foo;

MyClass *fooptr = &foo; // fooptr == NULL
fooptr = &reinterpret_cast<DummyStruct>(foo); // fooptr = &foo (the real address)
```

Comment: I don't think this is C99, though, and that's what he asked for.

Comment: @Thornley, The question states "anything working will be ok." Also, the question has been tagged with "c++."

Comment: and if he still wants to get teh addy, he can use teh boost::addressof

Comment: @litb, I have updated my answer with that, and a non-boost method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a reference that holds a null address. This is extremely bad practice, but here goes:

```
#ifdef NON_NULL
Foo realFoo;
Foo &foo = realFoo;
#else
Foo &foo = *(Foo*)NULL;
#endif
```

Please, don't do it this way. auto_ptr may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standard way to define something that has the address 0. Or rather, it's undefined since it would then be possible to dereference 0, which is undefined (or is it platform specific?) in the standard.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't have a C standard handy, but in C++ dereferencing the null pointer is undefined, and a constant 0 in pointer context is a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's got to be the question, but you want to have a pointer with a value of 0?

how about

```
void * bar = (void*) 0;
```

You don't have to do all that messing about: a pointer is just a number with which the compiler associates a type; if you want the number to be 0, assign 0.

Oh, and answering another question, it's not that the language has anything to do with it, it's just you don't necessarily know what is in location 0.  We had a lot of trouble with BSD code back in the day because on early BSD unices, *0 == 0 was reliably true.  So people would write things like

```
while(*c) doSomething();
```

because when they dereferenced the 0x00 at the end of a string, it looked at LOCATION 0 which had the VALUE 0.  Unfortunately, that wasn't necessarily true on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt there is a way to do this in standard C99.  In standard C++, you'd be hard put to reference the object once created, if you could create it, as dereferencing a null pointer constant is undefined, and a constant integral 0 in pointer constant is a null pointer constant.  (Yes, you could try `int i; i = 0; foo * p = reinterpret_cast<foo *>i; p->doSomething();` but the standard doesn't specify what reinterpret_cast<> does, other than in a vague and implementation-dependent way.)

So, my next question is what you're trying to accomplish here.  If you're trying to twist the language in odd and interesting ways, it doesn't twist that way according to the Standard.  If you've got a legitimate use for this, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close, just a step of pointer indirection away.

Judging by your code sample, there's no need to take the address of `foo`.
You can accomplish what you want by creating a function that allocates and instantiates `bar`.

So instead of:

```
DECL(foo);

int * bar = &foo;
```

you could have:

```
#define FOO_IS_NULL 0

int * getFoo() 
{  
    if( FOO_IS_NULL )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *tmp = 1234;
    return tmp;
}

int * bar = getFoo();
```

Note that this gets rid of the variable `foo` entirely.

The only caveat is that you now need to `free(bar)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what we have:

- C++ allows overloading `operator&` and has templates to do the work for you, but doesn't allow dereferencing the null pointer.
- C allows dereferencing the null pointer, as long as the address is taken afterwards. It also allows assigning `void*` to any pointer to an object.

Well, that's ideal. First, the C part, which is very easy. I don't understand your point that you cannot embed it into macros. It works fine for me.

```
#define foo_ (*(void*) 0)
```

Now, the C++ part. Put the stuff in nullp.hpp:

```
struct nullp { 
    struct proxy { 
        template<typename T> operator T*() { 
            return 0; 
        } 
    }; 

    proxy operator&() { 
        return omg(); 
    } 
} foo;
```

Now, all we need to do is to glue things together:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include "nullp.hpp"
#else
#define foo (*(void*) 0)
#endif
```

Now, you can use `&foo` and assign it to some pointer to some object-type.

Comment: Err, nevermind.  I misread your statement.  I do get a warning from GCC, though: "dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer".  With this kind of hackery, though, I'm sure it can be "safely" ignored (even though I would look for a better solution myself).

Comment: yeah, whole stuff is hackerish, but completely standard i believe. comeau also seem to support that view. no warning at least from it :)

Comment: In c, it's valid to dereference a `void*` - in C++ it's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Look, I'm sorry, but you're making this both too hard and too complicated.

If you want to call the thing in C, you need a pointer to function.  So, for example, you have

```
/* ptr to 0-ary function returning int */
int (*func)() = NULL ;    /* That's all you need. */

// elsewhere ....
int myfunc() { /* do a good thing */ }
func = myfunc ;       /* function name *is* its address */
```

Now, in later code you can do

```
if(!func) 
    (*func)();
else
    /* function not defined */
```

You don't need to mess with the loader, and you don't need --- and shouldn't use --- any zippy macros unless you *really* *really* have a strong reason for doing so.  This is all standard C.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using C++, you can use references:

```
int *foo = 0;
int &bar = *foo;
int *foo_addr = &bar; // gives NULL
```

Comment: note that dereferencing the null pointer formally is undefined. there are some inconsistencies in the standard about that though. it says it's UB, but it says otherwise in one place: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232 . tho probably no compiler will crash on your code.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, according to the C++ standard.  *foo is dereferencing a null pointer.  This can do anything, including appearing to work until the worst posible time.